# Version Error occurred when building Spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark

My spark version is 2.1.0, Hadoop version is 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0, JDK version 1.7, maven version 3.3.9

And add to pom.xml:

`<repository>
<id>cloudera</id>
<url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
</repository>`

When I built source code as `./dev/make-distribution.sh --name 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 --tgz  -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0`

And I got

```
[japson@localhost spark-2.1.0]$ ./dev/make-distribution.sh --name 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 --tgz  -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 -X
+++ dirname ./dev/make-distribution.sh
++ cd ./dev/..
++ pwd
+ SPARK_HOME=/home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0
+ DISTDIR=/home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0/dist
+ MAKE_TGZ=false
+ MAKE_PIP=false
+ MAKE_R=false
+ NAME=none
+ MVN=/home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0/build/mvn
+ ((  9  ))
+ case $1 in
+ NAME=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0
+ shift
+ shift
+ ((  7  ))
+ case $1 in
+ MAKE_TGZ=true
+ shift
+ ((  6  ))
+ case $1 in
+ break
+ '[' -z /home/japson/software/jdk1.7.0_79 ']'
+ '[' -z /home/japson/software/jdk1.7.0_79 ']'
++ command -v git
+ '[' ']'
++ command -v /home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0/build/mvn
+ '[' '!' /home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0/build/mvn ']'
++ tail -n 1
++ grep -v INFO
++ /home/japson/app/spark-2.1.0/build/mvn help:evaluate - 
 Dexpression=project.version -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 -X
+ VERSION='[ERROR] [Help 3] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException'
```

So, is there any solution？Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/), the solution is:

1. In you build directory(where you do the mvn command from) add directory:

   `.mvn` (with cmd `mkdir .mvn`)
2. In it create file

   `jvm.config`
3. Put the following line to `jvm.config`

   `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`